# With Foundation for Apps, how do I include a custom directive and use it?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying to migrate an existing web-app over to foundation for apps framework. I'm understanding how to access AngularJS functionality in the html templates and partials, but have been unsuccessful in getting access to angular in js.

The base app template comes with an empty app.js, but I'm uncertain in how to use this to include custom modules and directives.

Any examples or instruction on how to use my own app.js or just include custom directives would be appreciated.

---

### UPDATE

I can access angular now, the problem was that by default Foundation for Apps puts the app.js file before angular.js, so that is now fixed.

The new problem is that any javascript files (other than app.js) in the client/assets/js folder do not get copied over to the build folder.

Is this a bug? Or do I need to include files in some config file?

Comment: if you looking for angular framework for mobile, you better pick ionic framework. Unless if you going to build from scratch. You have all that you ask for within it. Some of the advance features that ionic have could save you a lot of time like the infinite scroll, delegation, modal, popup, pull to refresh etc. If your prefer other css styling you could always replace the default ionic.css, twitter bootstrap or other if you like.

Comment: Unfortunately your comment has nothing to do with what I'm trying to get help with.

Comment: are you using grunt?

Comment: the foundation for apps template uses Gulp, and while I'm not super versed with it, I'm thinking the answer is somewhere in the gulpfile.js, currently poking through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a variable in the included gulp.js file that sets the files to minify into app.js in the build directory:

```
var appJS = [
  'client/assets/js/app.js'
];
```

I used wildcards to include anything that I put into the js directory. That way I can still keep my typical `/js/controllers` `/js/directives` type of directory structure:

```
var appJS = [
  'client/assets/js/**/*.*'
];
```